# PYTHON : There is a function similar to ast.literal_eval ()?

Tags: python

I've got a problem with the utilisation of ast.literal_eval(). In the example below, I only want to convert the string (myText) to dictionnary. But ast.literal_eval() try to evaluate `<__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D64D88>` and give me an error. I completely anderstand this error but I would like to know if there is a way to avoid it (with an other function or with an other way to use the function ast.literal_eval)

```
import ast

myText = "{<__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D64D88>: value}"
ast.literal_eval(myText)

# Error: invalid syntax
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 4, in <module>
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\python27.zip\ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
#     node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
#   File "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\python27.zip\ast.py", line 37, in parse
#     return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
#   File "<unknown>", line 1
#     {<__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D64D88>: value}
#      ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax #
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Consider doing it manually, if you know that the `myText` is going to be fairly regular. 1 Strip the braces. 2. Split on comma. 3. Split each resulting string on the colon, and shove the parts into a dictionary.

Comment: What do you want to happen here?

Comment: Do you understand what `ast.literal_eval` does? If your example is verbatim, then neither the key nor the value in your dictionary representation is an actual literal.

Comment: If you are storing this kind of information as a string, you are probably trying to solve a problem the wrong way. What fundamental problem are you trying to solve/for what do you want to evaluate this string?

Comment: Your data is already irreversibly damaged. Using a smarter parser won't help.

Comment: I can try to exectute it manually like unwind said. In fact I try to read a text file. In this file I saved attributes of several instances and now I would like to get back these values. So in reality the string that I want to read is more like that : `{<__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D64D88>: {'name': 'theName'}, <__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D73F48>: {'name': 'theName'}}`

Comment: Maybe you want to be pickling/unpickling these objects instead.

Comment: It look like that ABM is right. I don't know was pickling/unpickling is (I am a complete beginner in python) but I just quickly ready some informations about it and it look good for what I want to do. I will search more about it ! Thanks everyone for the help !

Comment: Wow, it's like a textbook example of [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There is not any code that could possibly take the input `<__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D64D88>` and create an instance of the `myClass` class with the correct contents. It is like trying to make a cow out of a pile of *pictures of* hamburgers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want to do is dump your data using `pickle.dump` and load it using `pickle.load` (or equivalent, such as json, etc.). Using `repr(data)` to dump the data will cause problems like this.

If you just need to salvage the data you have already generated, you **might** get away with something like the following:

```
def my_literal_eval(s):
    s = re.sub(r"<__main__.myClass instance at 0x([^>]+)>", r'"<\1>"', s)
    dct = ast.literal_eval(s)
    return {myClass(): v for v in dct.itervalues()}
```

Example of usage:

```
>>> import ast, re
>>> class myClass(object): pass
... 
>>> myText = "{<__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D64D88>: {'name': 'theName'}, <__main__.myClass instance at 0x0000000052D73F48>: {'name': 'theName'}}"
>>> my_literal_eval(myText)
{<__main__.myClass object at 0x7fbdc00a4b90>: {'name': 'theName'}, <__main__.myClass object at 0x7fbdc0035550>: {'name': 'theName'}}
```

This will work only if the `myClass` instances don't have any useful information, but are only needed for identity. The idea is to first fix up the string by replacing the `<__main__.myClass instance ...>` strings with something that can be parsed by `ast.literal_eval`, and then replace those with actual `myClass` instances - provided these can be constructed without arguments, which hinges on the above assumption.

If this initial assumption doesn't hold, then your data is, as Ignacio [put it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774297/python-there-is-a-function-similar-to-ast-literal-eval#comment47679580_29774297), irreversibly damaged, and no amount of clever parsing will retrieve the lost bits.

Comment: thanks ! It look like perfect for what I want to do !