# python convert string of instance to instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, type-conversion, data-conversion

is there any way for me to convert a string of a python instance:

```
"<__main__.test instance at 0x0325E5D0>"
```

to an actual instance

```
<__main__.test instance at 0x0325E5D0>
```

while having keep the same data it had when being an actual instance, I haven't been able to find something like an *instance()* function that would act similar to *str()* or *int()*

i've tried using the suggested function shown here:
[PYTHON : There is a function similar to ast.literal_eval ()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774297/python-there-is-a-function-similar-to-ast-literal-eval)
but it doesn't work

advice would be much appreciated

Comment: No. This is impossible.

Comment: Do you know what `<__main__.test instance at 0x0325E5D0>` means?

Comment: what is it that you are trying to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: It's like trying to turn the street address of a building back into the building that used to be there after the whole city has been razed to the ground.

Comment: Use the `pickle` module. (as I said in my answer to the proposed duplicate)'

Comment: If the object still exists at that address, then there are ways (but it's not recommended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you maybe want is serialization to store your object for later use.

To save it

```
import pickle

your_class = ...

with open('my_instance.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(a, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

To load

```
import pickle
with open('my_instance.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)
```