# How can i get type of python object when it is enclosed in a string?

Tags: python, casting, type-conversion

I have a python object `a="123.50"` which is string `type(a)=string` 
I want something that tells me  variable `a` is `float` object.

I have tried `ast.literal_eval(value)` , but since it accepts every other things.

Is there anything similar to it `(ast.literal_eval)` ?

Comment: Try parsing the float and catch the error?..

Comment: It's your data, you should know what you want to get. It's context dependant. What do you want  `"1E1"` to be? A string? A float? An integer?

Comment: you can eval here, provided example in below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, its usual to just try it

```
>>> def floater(val):
...     try:
...             float(val)
...             return True
...     except ValueError:
...             return False
... 
>>> floater("123.45")
True
>>> floater("sinker")
False
```

Or you could just have python take a crack at it and report what it finds

```
>>> def what_is_it(val):
...     try:
...             return type(ast.literal_eval(val)).__name__
...     except:
...             return None
... 
>>> 
>>> what_is_it("113.44")
'float'
>>> what_is_it("1")
'int'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer [PYTHON : There is a function similar to ast.literal_eval ()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29774297/python-there-is-a-function-similar-to-ast-literal-eval).

Comment: What do you expect the [really dangerous `eval`](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) to do here that isn't covered by the safe `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: yes, you are correct, we can use ast module as well. eval is dangerous if we pass expressions.

Comment: You've edited your answer into something that doesn't answer the question - "Is there anything similar to it (ast.literal_eval) ?"